# Is Arbitrary code execution vulnerability in Firefox a myth?

Tags: remote, firefox, vulnerability, execution

Have you ever seen a live demo of one of those critical vulnerabilities that Firefox publishes?
Is it possible to run a program (i.e. Notepad) or download/install a new one, without user intervention, just visiting an URL? That's what Mozilla assures in the security advisories.
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox/
I've asked for help in other sites, and even offered a bounty, but no such luck. Note that I'm not talking about a new unpublished exploit, I just want to see one of those bugs that are public. I don't even need to see the source code, just a live demo.
The last demo of that type I saw was in 2000, affecting IE 5. http://www.guninski.com/chmtemp-desc.html

Comment: joeqwerty, EEAA, Zoredache, Tero Kilkanen, Katherine Villyard.
What part of my question didn't you understand? Moderator Shane Madden understood it perfectly. The only thing I understand clearly is that your are more willing to block this inconvenient question, than letting others contribute.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a myth.  [Exploit DB](http://www.exploit-db.com/) is the best place to find proof-of-concept attacks for publicly disclosed vulnerabilities.  Obviously not every vulnerability gets published there, but plenty do - the latest one I'm seeing against Firefox is [from April of last year](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/33386/).

Another good source of.. proof?.. of vulnerabilities in the major browsers is the Pwn2Own competition; which last year had 4 different zero-day attacks used against Firefox.

Comment: I've searching exploit-db.com for hours, and I've downloaded the old FF versions, but I only find scripts that crash FF. Besides, some of them applied to Add-ons, or required Java. Anyway, I think I'm not going to find any true remote code execution in versions newer than FF 4.0 or 11.0